# HTML5 Video - Javascript play() function is not working in jelly bean

Tags: android, html

In Jellybean, AutoPlay in HTML5 Video is not working. Javascript play() function is not working in jellybean

Comment: How do you mean, exactly? Describe your experience and issues - be specific

Comment: play() function to start html5 video is not working in jelly bean. Also HTML5 Video Tag have a attribute called "autoplay". So if we give this attribute, video should play automatically when it loads. But it's not happening in jelly bean.

Comment: try to load this url from your jelly bean phone, and play video http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: The second part, I understand. But what do you mean by "play() function to start html5 video is not working in jelly bean"? By specific.

Comment: if we are not using "autoplay" attribute, We need to start play html5. For that we normally using play() function like this. var video = document.getElementById("videotagid"); video.play(); .. In jelly bean play() function is not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. The play() function only works if it originates from user interaction. This was first implemented by iOS, and is meant to prevent auto play on the limited , and sometimes expensive, bandwidth of a cellphone.

Imagine being in a foreign country with roaming, and what it would cost if your phone would automatically start downloading a video.